# layout is broken in xib at xCode 8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xib

The xib is created last two years ago and it can be opened using xcode7 and xcode 8.2 but I think starting from xcode 8.3 almost every xib got problem. How can i solve this?

[image]

Comment: You can try to set "Opens in" option from "File Inspector", choose "Xcode 7.x". Maybe this will help

Comment: may I know there is no way instead of doing this? because every time I want to change something then I have to open that xib with xcode 7?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following Steps, May be These are helpful for you :-

1) Open your Storyboard in Xcode 8.

2) Click on the File Inspector.

3) In Interface Builder Document section, select Opens In "Xcode 7.x" instead of "Latest Xcode (8.0)".

4) On doing this, you will get an alert saying "Saving for Xcode 7.x will close your document and data for Xcode 8.0 features will be removed."

5) Click Save and Close and you will be able to open storyboard in Xcode 7.x.